# Force "show desktop" in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

I have recently migrated from Windows 7 to 10. Unfortunately classic <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't have such forceful behaviour as in previous iteration(s) of OS. For example it can't minimize full screen windows (so far all games I tested, e.g. Smite) which in Win 7 could be easily minimized. Is there a way of enabling old behaviour or some 3rd party app which adds this old feature back?

---

EDIT1: To be crystal clear - **the shortcut is working with standard windows**. Most of the fullscreen windows are the issue, they just got ignored and stay maximized and in foreground. In Windows 7 they could be minimized simply using mentioned <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: If the shortcut is not working then the application specifically is catching that shortcut.  I can confirm that the shortcut still works on Windows 10

Comment: I didn't write "it's not working" (it is fine for "ordinary" windows), I wrote that it doesn't work for some full screen applications (or rather their window).

Comment: My comment was a confirmation that the behavior of this shorcut has not changed in Windows 10.  An application has always been able to capture this shortcut in order to disable it.

Comment: Tested with exactly same applications (at a same time, I have Win 7 on other PC) and **the behavior of Win+D has changed**, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Could this be related to the Xbox game features?

Comment: I should thank you just for posting this question, i was searching for the shortcut itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unsuccessful in finding some hidden option in Windows itself, but I got luck in 3rd party software area. I wrote (sadly not totally universal) script for forceful minimization of all windows - reimplementation of <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. It is a script in AutoHotKey activated via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. `ignored` variable holds names of processes which the script should skip.

```
ignored := [ "Rainmeter.exe", "Nimi Places.exe", "mumble.exe" ]

hasValue(haystack, needle) {
    if(!isObject(haystack))
        return false
    if(haystack.Length()==0)
        return false
    for k,v in haystack
        if(v==needle)
            return true
    return false
}

!^D::
WinGet, win, List
Loop, %win%
{
    this_id := win%A_Index%
    WinGet, exe, ProcessName, ahk_id %this_id%
    if not hasValue(ignored, exe)
        WinMinimize, ahk_id %this_id%
}
```